# PHP: Is code like this possible?

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to have a user-defined list of game-maps. Because I don't know how many maps will be in the array at design time, I'm trying to dynamically create new variables to contain them. Is this even possible? Here's my failed attempt:

```
<?php
$maplist=array("map1.aamap.xml","map2.aamap.xml"); //edit this list with your maps
$rounds = 3;                 //times to play each map
/*======No need to edit below========*/
global $last;  //store the last played map               
class Map
{
    public $difficulty;
    public $played;  //amount of times played
}
foreach($maplist as $i => $element)
{
    $element = $map[$i];
    $map[$i] = new Map();
}
//snipped other code here
$map[$i]->$played = $x++;  //increment the times played counter <-- FAILS HERE
?>
```

Parser says: `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property`

Is something like this even feasible in this manner?

Comment: the line `$map[$i]->$played = $x++;` is out of loop and `$i` doesn't exist, hence the error

Comment: @Kumar yes but that is not the problem here. editing the code and replacing $i with 1 also gives the same error

Comment: @Kumar: No. `$i` is defined at global scope, so it will still exist after the loop, keeping the value of the key of the last array element (`1` in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

```
<?php
$maplist=array("map1.aamap.xml","map2.aamap.xml"); //edit this list with your maps
$rounds = 3;                 //times to play each map
/*======No need to edit below========*/
global $last;  //store the last played map
```

Since you are on the global scope here, not inside a function, there is no need for `global`.

```
class Map
{
    public $difficulty;
    public $played;  //amount of times played
}
foreach($maplist as $i => $element)
{
    $element = $map[$i];
```

Is some code missing here?  You are not using `$element` within the loop, so this assignment is not needed.

```
    $map[$i] = new Map();
}
//snipped other code here
$map[$i]->$played = $x++;  //increment the times played counter <-- FAILS HERE
```

The syntax to access a member variable is `$object->variable`, not `$object->$variable`.  The latter one will evaluate `$variable` and use the value as variable name (E.g., if `$variable = "foo"`, this will try to access `$object->foo`).

Use `$map[$i]->played = $x++;` instead.

Comment: I too feel stupid but I really didnt see $i defined at the global level, is the $i in foreach available after foreach ends? I am still feeling like a stupid

Answer (score 2):

When accessing the properties of a class, you don't want to use the `$` in front of the property name itself.

Replace `$map[$i]->$played = $x++;` with `$map[$i]->played = $x++;` to solve the `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property` error.

Comment: yeah, i just realized that. *embarassed*

Answer (score 0):

You could override the magic methods to provide dynamic properties if you wish:

```
public function __get($name)
{
...
}

public function __set($name, $value)
{
...
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members

Within each of these functions you could store the data in some internal array structure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the $ when accessing properties of an instance. Simple use $map[$i]->played. Have a look on the [OOP basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).